# JQuery mobile theme roller 1.4.3

Tags: jquery-mobile

Ok.  So all the version of the Theme roller before 1.4.3 have  options to choose a **start** and **end** color which creates a gradient on whatever you want.

Does anyone know how to get gradients in to a version 1.4.3 Theme?

**version 1.4.3 (Below)**
[image: A shot of Body in version 1.4.3]

**version 1.3.2 (Below)**
  [image: A shot of Body in version 1.3.2]

Is there even any reason to use 1.4.3?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here: http://jquerymobile.com/upgrade-guide/1.4/ at the section titled Custom Theme.

> Because gradients are no longer part of the default theme, they can't
>   be set with the ThemeRoller anymore either. You can still use
>   gradients, but you have to manually copy the background-image settings
>   from your current theme into your 1.4 theme CSS file.

```
.ui-body-a,
.ui-page-theme-a .ui-body-inherit,
html .ui-bar-a .ui-body-inherit,
html .ui-body-a .ui-body-inherit,
html body .ui-group-theme-a .ui-body-inherit,
html .ui-panel-page-container-a {
        background: #333 /*{a-body-background-color}*/;
        border-color: #111 /*{a-body-border}*/;
        color: #fff /*{a-body-color}*/;
        text-shadow: 0 /*{a-body-shadow-x}*/ 1px /*{a-body-shadow-y}*/ 0 /*{a-body-shadow-radius}*/ #111 /*{a-body-shadow-color}*/;
        /* Copied from 1.3 custom theme: */
        background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from( #444 ), to( #222 )); /* Saf4+, Chrome */
        background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient( #444, #222 ); /* Chrome 10+, Saf5.1+ */
        background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient( #444, #222 ); /* FF3.6 */
        background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient( #444, #222 ); /* IE10 */
        background-image:      -o-linear-gradient( #444, #222 ); /* Opera 11.10+ */
        background-image:         linear-gradient( #444, #222 );    
}
```